# SQL Table Matrix

Tags: sql, database, many-to-many, normalization

Forgive me if the terminology of the title is incorrect, what im describing is an intermediate table which enables a kind of many-to-many relationship between 2 or more tables.

In this case, a single table holds data which applies to other tables which aren't necessarily related to each other.

Specifically a site:

- Page A and B from table Pages belongs to Site 1.
- User A from table Users also belongs to Site 1, but User B belongs to Site 2

So the middle table at the moment looks like this:

```
id | site | page | user
-----------------------
 1 | 1    | A    | null
 2 | 1    | B    | null
 3 | 1    | null | A
 4 | 2    | null | B
```

Despite this appearing to become a cause of many problems, the system would be supported
by the database being fully normalized, the deletion of a user for example would delete
any record associated with it in the matrix, updates would also cascade.

I understand that the amount of data in here could get pretty high, which is why it would only be used to link reference tables containing between 5-200 records.  Mass record tables such as posts or media containing upwards of several thousand records and growing that are connected to sites for example would be flattened and store the site ID directly.

Finally the reason I need a solution like this is because I need the elements to be assigned to a customizable number of sites, otherwise the only options are: 1 site, all sites, or no sites.

So my question is, is this an effective method?

Comment: I've got to tell you, this table will make your system **not** normalized. It's _going_ to cause you problems.  You can properly normalize your database and have the requirements you list.

Comment: Then how would you do it?<br />
edit: http://sqlrelationship.com/many-to-many-relationship/ <br />
ok so its called a junction table.  the example on the site does it the same way i've tried, with the exception that i've made it work for both users and pages, so parhaps i should split it into 2 tables?

Comment: I also agree normalization would serve you better. For example in your **pages** table have a *siteID* column which contains the site; in the **user** table also have a *siteID* to designate which site the user belongs to.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i intended to begin with, however it does need to be a many to many relationship in some shape or form because pages and users need to be assignable to more than one site.  Im trying to make it perfectly normalized, there is cascading taking place with this junction table although the method in general seems a little sloppy.  are many to many relationships decremental to normalization then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to be able to assign pages/users to more than one site.  However, the two aren't otherwise related (given current known requirements).  And even if they were, there are probably better ways to show any relationships.

For whatever reason, you seem to think that having a normalized table won't enable the relationships; here's how this will work.

```
UserSite
==========
userId  -- fk reference user.id
siteId  -- fk reference site.id
```

The tuple [`userId`, `siteId`] should be unique.  It is expected there will be many users on a site, and a user may be present on more than one site.  This relationship will track between users and sites.  Want to enable a site for a user?  Add them to this table.  Want to disable a site for a user?  Remove them from this table (or have a 'disabled' column or somesuch).

You're going to want a *separate* table `PageSite` That records the relationships between pages and sites.  Unless there's something *else* you're doing with the relationship `page`-`user`, you don't need to put them in the same table.

Comment: Thank you.  It was indeed messy of me to use the same table to perform more than one junction.  I am satisfied that this will enable the functionality I am trying to create.